# Clear all elements from multiple list

Tags: c#, list

say if I had multiple lists created to hold some value. For example:

```
List<string> ListA= new List<string>();
List<string> ListB= new List<string>();
List<string> ListC= new List<string>();
List<int> ListD= new List<int>();
List<int> ListE= new List<int>();
```

Are there anyway to clear all list with one-liner? Currently, I'm doing this:

```
ListA.Clear();
ListB.Clear();
ListC.Clear();
ListD.Clear();
ListE.Clear();
```

Comment: Have you thought about 1 list, and a custom class?

Comment: I can give you a longer way `new List<IList>() { ListA , ListB, ListC, ListD, ListE }.ForEach(x => x.Clear());`

Comment: or  `public static void ClearAll(params IList[] lists) => lists.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Clear());`

Answer (score 2):

No - not really.

You could create an extension method for this or just move it to a function. Whether that would be better would depend on the situation.

Unless you have nested lists or a or something i would definitely not bother.

You could of course add them all to a collection, and use `foreach` to call `.clear()` on each list but again - this depends on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could, and without using another collection:

```
foreach (var list in Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select<int, IList>(i => i switch { 0 => ListA, 1 => ListB, 2 => ListC, 3 => ListD, 4 => ListE })) list.Clear();
```

Not that it's any more readable than using 5 lines.

A cleaner solution solution would be to define a helper method:

```
void Clear(params IList[] lists)
{
    foreach (var list in lists) list.Clear();
}
```

Then:

```
Clear(ListA, ListB, ListC, ListD, ListE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some longer uglier ways...

```
new List<IList>() { ListA , ListB, ListC, ListD, ListE }.ForEach(x => x.Clear());
```

and

```
public static void ClearAll(params IList[] lists) 
    => lists.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Clear());

// usage

ClearAll(ListA , ListB, ListC, ListD, ListE);
```

However, instead of multiple lists, you could just 1 list and a custom class

Comment: `ToList()` adds unnecessary overhead; why not just use `foreach` to iterate `lists` directly?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, while you are indeed correct and i cant argue. It was kind of not the bastion of prefect programming. Additionally,  when someone asks for code on one line, chances are they are less likely caring about a couple of more stack calls and those pesky allocations :)

Comment: Fair enough, it just stands out as an easily avoidable inefficiency :)

Comment: I giggled after reading 'It was kind of not the bastion of prefect programming.' and i will definitely use that phrase more often now.